# How to add a seperator between two TreeTable ini jface

Tags: treeview, jface

I have created an eclipse plugin project using one of the sample templates available. I want to have two viewers side by side. I am able to accomplish this. But the thing is..there is no seperator as such. It basically looks like this:

```
TreeViewer1    TreeViewer2
  .              .
  ....comp1      ....Comp3
  .              .
  ....comp2      ....Comp4
```

I want to have it something like this:

```
TreeViewer1  |  TreeViewer2
  .          |    .
  ....comp1  |    ....Comp3
  .          |    .
  ....comp2  |    ....Comp4
```

I tried adding 'new Label(parent, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.VERTICAL);' But the UI entirely got messed up.

This is the code

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) 
{
viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
        | SWT.V_SCROLL);
viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
// Provide the input to the ContentProvider
viewer.setInput(new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});

new Label(parent, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.VERTICAL);

viewer2 = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
        | SWT.V_SCROLL);
viewer2.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
viewer2.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
// Provide the input to the ContentProvider
viewer2.setInput(new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});

}
```

[image] Requesting you to share your thoughts.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `LayoutData` properly on every `Control`.

Start Reading this standard article about layout managers in SWT

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html